# How to store token in cookies in reactjs frontend on call by login post method to server

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express

this is my login post method in the reactjs frontend

```
const login = () => {
Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/users/login", {
  email: values.email,
  password: values.password,
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data);
}).catch(err =>{
  console.log(err)
})
```

};

this is my expressjs server side, here i have login post method for reactjs frontend, where iam on response i want to send token to set in cookie whenever user post on login method, below is code for login post method

```
login: (req, res) => {
const body = req.body;
console.log("req.body :", req.body);
getUserByEmail(body.email, (err, results) => {
  console.log("results :", results);

  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  if (!results) {
    res.json({
      status: "failure",
      msg: "Invalid email or password",
    });
  }
  const result = compareSync(body.password, results.password);
  const SECRET_KEY = "xyz123";
  if (result) {
    results.password = undefined;
    const jsontoken = sign({ result: results }, SECRET_KEY, {
      expiresIn: "1h",
    });
    //   console.log(res)
    res.cookie("token", jsontoken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      domain: "http://localhost:3000/login",
    });
    return res.json({
      status: "Success",
      msg: "login Successfully",
      token: jsontoken,
    });
  } else {
    return res.json({
      status: "failure",
      msg: "Invalid email or password",
    });
  }
});
```

},

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, that is actually more secure, is tell the browser using headers on the response to create a cookie.

There is a header in HTTP called `Set-Cookie`, which is responsible to do just that, you can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie.

The way you add it to your request on express is by calling the `res.cookie` function on your express request handler. I would suggest telling the cookie to be `httpOnly` in order for it to not be accessible through JS code, this is just a way to avoid XSS attacks.
Here you have an example to how to achieve that:

```js
res.cookie('token', jsontoken, { httpOnly: true });
```

Then in order to access the cookie, you would need to use the `cookieParser` middleware which is responsible in putting all the cookies the client sent in `req.cookies`.
You use it this way:

```js
app.use(express.cookieParser());
```